# How to switch phone line when clicking on a phone number link?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, call, esim

I'm using an iPhone 14 with iOS 16.5 and two SIM cards.

When calling someone from `Contacts` I can select which line to choose to call him. When dialing a phone number in the `Phone` app I can also select which line I'd like to use for this call.

But when I click on a phone number link, e.g. on a website, I don't see any possibility to switch to another line, so the default line will be used.

Is there any way to switch the line when I click on a phone number link?

Comment: Have you tried long-clicking?

Comment: @Thinkr Yes, I did but there's also no such option. Just the usual, FaceTime, Send Message …

Comment: Oh. I thought there might be (not using 2 SIMS). Why not just copying the phone number to Phone app?

Comment: @Thinkr Yes, I could copy the phone number to the Phone app and then select the line. But this isn't really convenient.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing,. but you can try to search for some apps with that functinality in app store or manually copying the phone number and pasting it into the Phone app

Answer (score 0):

Apple has an excellent support documnet entitled [Using Dual SIM with an eSIM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209044).  I encourage you to review it as it contains a lot f excellent info. That said, I have excerpted the relevant part to your question

> #### Switch phone numbers for a call
>
> If you're using the keypad, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Enter the phone number.
> 2. Tap the phone number, near the top of the screen.
> 3. Tap the number you want to use

If you tap the number on a website, you have to do this on the dialing screen where the number is visible.  It may require you to disconnect first then redial using your selected number or just copy/paste number into the dial pad. I’ve used the second method often when using this feature internationally.

Comment: I know this but it's rather a workaround than a convenient solution.

Comment: Tapping a phone number link assumes the default number; it a “quick action”. To get what you want, you have to manually intervene

Comment: Isn't this what I've [proposed in the comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460976/how-to-switch-phone-line-when-clicking-on-a-phone-number-link/460991#comment677096_460976)?